# Get texture coordinates of mouse position in SDL2?

Tags: c, sdl-2

I have the strict requirement to have a texture with resolution (let's say) of 512x512, always (even if the window is bigger, and SDL basically scales the texture for me, on rendering). This is because it's an emulator of a classic old computer assuming a fixed texture, I can't rewrite the code to adopt multiple texture sizes and/or texture ratios dynamically.

I use `SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize()` for the purpose I've described above.

Surely, when this is rendered into a window, I can get the mouse coordinates (window relative), and I can "scale" back to the texture position with getting the real window size (since the window can be resized).

*However, there is a big problem here*. As soon as window width:height ratio is not the same as the texture's ratio (for example in full screen mode, since the ratio of modern displays would not match of the ratio I want to use), there are "black bars" at the sides or top/bottom. Which is nice, since I want always the same texture ratio, fixed, and SDL does it for me, etc. However I cannot find a way to ask SDL where is my texture rendered exactly inside the window based on the fixed ratio I forced. Since I need the position within the texture only, and the exact texture origin is placed by SDL itself, not by me.

Surely, I can write some code to figure out how those "black bars" would change the origin of the texture, but I can hope there is a more simple and elegant way to "ask" SDL about this, since surely it has the code to position my texture somewhere, so I can re-use that information.

My very ugly (can be optimized, and floating point math can be avoided I think, but as the first try ...) solution:

```
static void get_mouse_texture_coords ( int x, int y )
{
    int win_x_size, win_y_size;
    SDL_GetWindowSize(sdl_win, &win_x_size, &win_y_size);
    // I don't know if there is more sane way for this ...
    // But we must figure out where is the texture within the window,
    // which can be changed since the fixed ratio versus the window ratio (especially in full screen mode)
    double aspect_tex = (double)SCREEN_W / (double)SCREEN_H;
    double aspect_win = (double)win_x_size / (double)win_y_size;
    if (aspect_win >= aspect_tex) {
            // side ratio correction bars must be taken account
            double zoom_factor = (double)win_y_size / (double)SCREEN_H;
            int bar_size = win_x_size - (int)((double)SCREEN_W * zoom_factor);
            mouse_x = (x - bar_size / 2) / zoom_factor;
            mouse_y = y / zoom_factor;
    } else {
            // top-bottom ratio correction bars must be taken account
            double zoom_factor = (double)win_x_size / (double)SCREEN_W;
            int bar_size = win_y_size - (int)((double)SCREEN_H * zoom_factor);
            mouse_x = x / zoom_factor;
            mouse_y = (y - bar_size / 2) / zoom_factor;
    }
}
```

Where `SCREEN_W` and `SCREEN_H` are the dimensions of the my texture, quite misleading by names, but anyway. Input parameters `x` and `y` are the window-relative mouse position (reported by SDL). `mouse_x` and `mouse_y` are the result, the texture based coordinates. This seems to work nicely. However, is there any sane solution or a better one?

The code which calls the function above is in my event handler loop (which I call regularly, of course), something like this:

```
void handle_sdl_events ( void ) {
    SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
    switch (event.type) {
        case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
            get_mouse_texture_coords(event.motion.x, event.motion.y);
            break;
        [...]
```

Comment: How do you render? I don't think SDL would produce letterbox if you never asked for it (e.g. `RenderSetLogicalSize`, `RenderSetViewport`, `RenderSetScale`, etc.).

Comment: Yes, I'm using RenderSetLogicalSize indeed. Sorry to forget to mention that. But then since SDL somehow must know how to letterboxing, they should provide a way to figure out what the mouse coordinate in relation of the texture placement, since it must has the code to do it, it's my sane assumption that I can ask that data, so I don't need that horrific code to do the calculation myself :) But if there is no other way than I did, well ... then I will do this ... Thanks for the comment!

Comment: I don't get that.. If you have `RenderSetLogicalSize` then SDL should rescale events to this rectangle, applyting both letterboxing and scaling, so no extra tansform is required (I haven't tried it, but looking at SDL code looks like that't the case). If that's not the case for you - could you make minimal complete example and edit it into the question? You could get resulting viewport via `SDL_RenderGetVewport`, but that's what SDL does internally - so, strange.

Comment: Well, I did an example program to put pixel on the reported mouse coords. Then I experienced the problems which made me to ask the question. I'm sorry, maybe I am not the best at SDL2 stuffs, I'm still try to figure out things, so it can be easily my mistake. I just do RenderSetLogicalSize, and I use the event handler to get mouse events and utilize the `x` and `y` of the event. Maybe I should handle mouse otherwise, and that is the problem? Sorry for the stupid question ...

Comment: That's perfectly valid question, it's just very hard to answer it without seeing your code. I've written a test just now and in it SDL reports events in logical size space - that's why I've asked for your code. How do you handle events, at least? Full minimal example would be better of course.

Comment: Indeed, it seems I am quite bad to express my problem. I've tried to add some additional information into my question by editing it. Thanks for pointing out the lack of enough information on my problem.

Comment: You _should_ get mouse events in logical space with that event handling, unless you switch logical size on the fly. I even get negative coordinates when moving mouse in letterbox area. If that's not the case for you - minimal complete compilable verifyable example illustrating your problem seems to be the only way.